# Naming the forces of the Purgatory?

Tags: creature-design, religion, worldbuilding-process, mythology

I'm trying to build a world loosely based on ideas about afterlife in Christianity. In my world God is nowhere to be found and supernatural forces are split into three factions: Hell, Heaven & Purgatory. Each faction has a ruler, and army of angels and human spirits.

Michael rules heaven with army of angels and saints (spirits of good people)

Lucifer rules hell with his army of devils (fallen angels) and demons (spirits of evil people).

Gabriel rules purgatory where angels loyal to him fallowed him after disappearance of god. Gabriel believes that humans are flawed, but their uniqueness is in the journey for improvement.

All three factions covertly compete for human souls. Good people go to heaven, bad people go to hell and those who are flawed but have a chance in redemption go to purgatory.

How to call the angels and human spirits in the service of the Purgatory?

Preferably I would like something that references Christianity, Judaism is OK too.

**1st Edit**

I don't need biblically correct, just names at least loosely connected with Christianity, that make sense in my world.  I don't want to introduce supernatural beings from other religions, like  Shintoism or Hinduism or whatever.

I added purgatory because good & evil duality is very boring and has been done to death. Three way fights are much more interesting, whenever one side starts winning the other two gang up together against it, until the new leader emerges when alliances shift again. The unstable dynamics gives me more interesting background to work with.

**Conclusion**

After some thoughts I decided to combine suggestions from Werrf & Pedro Gabriel.

I decided to keep the name of the third realm as Purgatory, but will use ideas from  Sheol. My reasoning is that the term Purgatory is known while the Sheol isn't.

I'll call the angels that rule the third realm watchers since that name fits with my story and there's apocryphal references in Books of Enoch. The alternative shepherds was also good but reminds me too much of Jesus. And those angels are far from good shepherds.

I'll call the human spirits that serve the watchers Rephaim since it has a somewhat sinister sound. The translation shades fits great into my story.

In the end I know that is far from biblically correct, but I don't strive for correctness. So I decided to use elements that I believe serve my storytelling best and at least to my ears sounds good.

In short my idea is described below:

God is absent and without it "angels" play a wicked game of who collects the most human souls by peddling their influence to humans using souls they already have as pawns.

After the soul is sent into one of this"realms", the "angels" might consider it useful enough to return it to Earth in order to bring more souls. They offer the soul a deal, go back to Earth to do their bidding as saint, demon or rephaim, in return you will receive respite from torture, chance to save loved ones or harm your enemies. While the soul is on the Earth, it's job is to influence humans toward the path that leads toward their own realm. Spirits in general work on edge cases, if someone is a remorseless killer, saints & rephaim wouldn't bother with someone who is destined to hell. However as soon as the human soul could go either way, they try to influence it.

Comment: I don't read Bible but nephilim?

Comment: Dante this question is pretty opinion based so I voted to close it.  This does not mean it is not interesting just that it is not objectively answerable.  I will say (in using the comments to give you some small answer) that purgatory is quite undefined in Catholic teachings.  To my knowledge it makes NO appearance in the bible at all.  Also Nephilim is a ripoff of the Diablo series so I would suggest avoiding it for original fiction.

Comment: This is NOT opinion based. I'm writing an answer on angelology, so please don't close it. Also, Nephilim DOES appears on the Bible, on the book of Genesis.

Comment: @James It is Nephalem in the Diablo franchise: Beings born from Angels and Demons. More powerful than either parent and the choice to turn either good or evil. The name would be very appropriate, but you're bound to attract some unwanted lawyer attention. (If not from Blizzard themselves, then from Activision their parent company.)

Comment: How would they sue? The Nephilim belong to the milenar jewish tradition!

Comment: Also, Nephilim are angels that came down from Heaven and bred Giants with mortal women. Those Giants were sinners that precipitated the events of the Flood. So, they are more akin to demons than purgatory angels. Even though it could be said that the Nephilim correspond to the Watchers, not demons.

Comment: I wasn't referring to a legal issue, I am just saying many people will know the reference.

Comment: They will know the reference from a videogame, but they won't know the true reference. You said that Nephilim don't appear on the Bible. That is not true. Saying that Nephilim shouldn't be used because of Diablo, is like saying that Zeus shouldn't be used because of God of War.

Comment: Is the idea that those souls in Purgatory eventually travel to either Heaven or Hell? If so, how does that factor into the rivalry? Or do they stay in Purgatory forever?

Comment: The series Supernatural had about the same premise. God missing, Heaven and Hell battling and gathering souls. Lucifer vs. Michael. They had a purgatory as well but nobody was running it. Here is a link to perhaps inspire you: http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Purgatory

Comment: Exactly, Eric. Purgatory IS on the side of Heaven. Purgatory is like a place where the souls, after being purified, enter Heaven (NOT Hell). It is like the shower you take before going to the swimming pool. Pitting Purgatory against Heaven is not compatible with Christianity, just like it doesn't make sense to pit the shower against the pool. However, the OP edited his question saying that it isn't obligatory to be biblically correct, so maybe we can be a little less rigid.

Comment: Perhaps since purgatory is the place you go after death but before heaven it would be cool to have Death himself (the horsemen) running it.

Comment: @Erik All the souls in any realm stays there for good. However if soul is sent back to Earth as saint, demon or watcher, it could potentially redeem its sins or make a new ones. The choice is only on Earth.

Comment: @Dante: What you said is little problematic from the jewish-christian tradition. I'm not saying that it isn't an interesting idea, just mentioning that you're borrowing aspects from one tradition and contradicting other aspects from the same tradition you're borrowing. I'm not saying that you shouldn't do it, just saying that you'll make christian theologians pretty confused with your plot. Namely this: Purgatory was meant to be temporary, not eternal. Also, if the Earth is a place to redeem sins, then Earth is Purgatory, so there is no need for Purgatory in the first place.

Comment: If you haven't read it yet, you should really read the [Incarnations of Immortality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incarnations_of_Immortality) series by Piers Anthony, as it has a lot of similarities to your idea.

Comment: Finally, hellbound souls are not retrievable ever again. They made their final choice. Hell and Heaven are eternal and souls are fixed on them for eternity. These are the things that contradict christianity's notions of these three realms. Again, I'm not saying you shouldn't do it. After all, the God of War videogame patently contradicts many aspects from the greek mythology. But just so that you know, since you said you wanted to base your plot on a christian's point of view regarding angels.

Comment: I agree with @James that this is too opinion-based, but I'm not going to mod-hammer it closed yet. Dante, you need to give some criteria for what makes one answer better than another; otherwise, this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: This is at best tangential to the question, but there's a really interesting story that follows a similar vein. Read [Myths over Miami](http://www.miaminewtimes.com/news/myths-over-miami-6393117) for a story of street children creating their own religion from bits and pieces of Christian mythology. The article's accuracy is dubious, but it's still a fascinating idea.

Comment: @HDE226868 I tried to describe to the best of my knowledge why the answers I choose are the best. Criteria  I used were 1st the connection with Christianity or alternatively Judaism. 2nd did the names at least  somewhat described the forces I needed.  3rd did the names sound right.  4th Were the names known

Comment: @Werrf Lovely story

Comment: Purguloids, Purgatrons, Purgeans, Purg-burgers, Purgliners (Ich bin ein...), the Purg-herd, Purg-merga (military wing), Purgs in Space (assuming they're in space), Purglets, Purgamon, Purgolators (barrista wing), asPurgers (the socially awkward, tech, geekery, and science wing), Purganauts, Purglars (thievery wing)....   Ah, I think I'm out.  For now.

Comment: Have you read Piers Anthony's Incarnations of Immortality series? Your reviewers are going to wonder if you have...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a hebrew scholar, this is entirely from a layman's perspective

### [Sheol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheol)

Something you may want to investigate is the concept of *[Sheol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheol)*, from early Hebrew mythology. This is distinct from later concepts of a divided afterlife in heaven or hell; in earlier times, Sheol was similar to the greek Hades, a place of darkness and quiet where all the dead, righteous or unrighteous, went after death.

In Christianity, Sheol evolved into Hell, the place of torment to which all souls go if they're not saved by Jesus. There are apocryphal stories that tell of Jesus going [into the edge of hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbo#Limbo_of_the_Patriarchs) and retrieving the biblical patriarchs to take them to heaven - this is probably born of the older idea of Sheol as a place where everyone went. It's also the part that is referenced in the Apostles creed with "He descended into hell".

For your scenario, you could consider Sheol to be that third place, distinct from both heaven and Hell, where those who died with original sin but did not commit terrible crimes to deserve hell could be sent.

People (shades) who were in Sheol could be called *Rephaites* or *Rephaim*, though that name also refers to a tribe of giants. This could be a good name for those spirits and angels trying to redeem themselves.

Comment: I second your motion, since Sheol would be less problematic from a jewish-christian point of view than pitting Purgatory against Heaven. But Sheol is, like you said, more analogous with Hades, where the shadows of the dead dwelt, without suffering nor joy. Like the darkness and quietness of the tomb. So, Sheol would never stand for penitence... the dwellers of such place would be more of a representative of nihilism, than penitence or morally grey areas.

Comment: What about Limbo, instead of Sheol or Purgatory?

Comment: Limbo could work, but it's not a biblical term; rather it's a description of a part of hell, meaning "The edge of hell". Limbo also has its own meaning in the modern vernacular, much more associated with the suspension of activity and the darkness and quietness of the tomb you mentioned for Sheol.

Comment: The OP never mentioned that it should be a biblical term, only that it should reference Judeo-Christianity. As for quietness you are right, except for this: souls of Limbo yearn for Heaven, while the souls of Sheol don't yearn for anything. Also, Limbo is the epitome of a morally grey area.

Comment: Sheol works too, I just want to avoid good evil duality since it quickly becomes boring.  I think Rephaim is a very good name for angels in that place, sounds old & sinister. Now I just need name for the human spirits analogous to saints and demons. Or I could call the angels watchers and the spirits Rephaim.

Comment: Call the angels Watchers and the human spirits Rephaim. Also, humans spirits shouldn't be named demons, but rather sinners. Demons are angels, not humans.

Comment: @Dante Make the human spirits Rephaim, and the angels *Shepherds*, guiding and guarding their charges towards the light.

Comment: The whole premise of my story is that God is somehow absent and "angels" decided to play a wicked game of who collects the most human souls by peddling their influence to humans using souls they already have  as pawns.So  after the soul is sent into one of this"realms", the "angels" might consider the soul useful enough to bring them more souls. They offer them a deal to temporarily send it back to Earth to do their bidding as saint, demon or something. The deal might be respite from torture, or a chance to save loved ones or harm your enemies. It's also a chance for betrayal.

Comment: @Werrf  Sounds good.

Comment: @PedroGabriel Pardon my lack of religious knowledge but aren't demons just evil spirits while fallen angels are called devils?

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski: Acording to Christian angelology, "demons", "devils", "fallen angels" and "evil spirits" are completely interchangeable (with the caveat for evil spirits which may refer to phantoms of the damned deceased, which are not demons, because they are not angels)

Answer (score 26):

Kingledion is right. You can't have a christian view where God is nowhere to be found and the angels rule over the Three Kingdoms. However, if you still wish to proceed with this idea, here are my suggestions:

---

First of, I wouldn't recomend Gabriel to rule over Purgatory. I would recomend Raphael or Uriel.

Raphael is an archangel mentioned on the Book of Tobit and he is seen as having healing powers. According to Catholicism, he is one of the patron saints of Medicine. Since Purgatory is seen as a place of purification, this could be seen as a form of healing.

As for Uriel, even though his name isn't mentioned in the Bible, he is an archangel present on jewish tradition that says that he was the one that was sent to guard the Doors of Eden with a fiery sword. Since Purgatory is a fiery place analogous with the Door of Paradise, that will only open after penance has been achieved, I think he is a fitting character.

---

Another source you **must** consider for you to study Angelolgy from a christian point of view are the writings of the Pseudo-Dyonisius Areopagite. He orderer the angels according to six hierarchies: Seraphim, Cherubim, Thrones, Dominations, Virtues, Powers, Principalities, Archangels and Angels.

Note, these are seven hierarchies that correspond to both angels *and* demons. It is probable that what we call archangels would be actually seraphim, the higher ranking. Lucifer could be a seraphim and all the other fallen angels could belong to any other rank below him.

So, as for angels of Purgatory, you would have to rank them according to this hierarchy too. However, you could make a rank more prevalent on the Purgatory side of the struggle than on the others.

The hierarchies are divided in three spheres: The higher sphere includes Seraphim, Cherubim and Thrones - these are closer to God. The middle sphere the Dominations, Powers and Virtues - these are intermediates between the divine and earthly realms. And the inferior the Principalities, Archangels and Angels - these are closer to humans and the world, which they guard.

I think the inferior spheres would be nearer to humans and therefore, would be more compassionate for their frailty. But you can imagine other alternatives, just study each hierarchy's properties:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_angelology

---

Another hypothesis would be to use The Watchers. Those were featured on the recent Noah movie.

Basically they aren't present on canonical books, but in apocryphal books, like the Book of Enoch. They fell on Earth because they pitied the fallen human race. But they are not equal to the demons, who fell because they rejected God and hated humans.

So, the Watchers, while un-ortodox from a religious point of view, are actually a kind of intermediate state between angel and demon.

You also have a list of names: "And these are the names of their leaders: Sêmîazâz, their leader, Arâkîba, Râmêêl, Kôkabîêl, Tâmîêl, Râmîêl, Dânêl, Êzêqêêl, Barâqîjâl, Asâêl, Armârôs, Batârêl, Anânêl, Zaqîêl, Samsâpêêl, Satarêl, Tûrêl, Jômjâêl, Sariêl. 8. These are their chiefs of tens."

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watcher_(angel)

---

Finally, I would refer you to Dante's Purgatorio. Though the angels, as far as I remember, aren't named there, there are many names which you could use as characters from your book, even angelic ones.

I would also like to say that I like Lu22's idea of calling the humans, The Penitent. It is absolutely in keeping with the christian's idea of Purgatory.

Comment: I did take the poster's pre-requisites and go from there. He said he wanted something taken from Christianism or Judaism... but his plot isn't compatible with Christianity. This isn't about opinion, it's about theology. Ask any theologically-literate christian. So yeah, it is "contrary to known science" if you count theology in. HOWEVER: after my disclaimer, I went on to answer the OP's question. I think I did it and managed to do it with good references on christianity and judaism, which is what the OP asked. If the OP thinks I missed anything, he may comment and say what I didn't get.

Comment: Any person that is trying to build a world based on christian angelology MUST know about Pseudo-Dyonisius Areopagite. Christian angelology began with him. This isn't opinion. This is fact.

Comment: Excellent answer.  So Nephilim for the angels, Watchers for the human spirits and Raphael or Uriel for their leader. Works for me very well. Will read about Pseudo-Dyonisius Areopagite to get some ideas.

Comment: @Dante: I'm sorry I induced you in error. The Nephilim ARE humans, NOT angels. The Nephilim are an evil breed of Giants that resulted from the intercourse between the sons of God with the daughters of men. These daughters of men are the daughters of Cain, but there is no agreement on jewish authorities whether the sons of God are fallen angels OR simply the sons of Seth, one of the faithful descendants of Adam. So the Nephilim are human, even if they could be descendants of angels.

Comment: Rather, name the angels Watchers and name the humans as Penitents

Comment: @PedroGabriel OK watchers for the angels. However Penitent  has too many syllables, how about ruthful http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ruthful  for the human spirits?

Comment: @Dante: English is not my native language... but from what I read on the dictionary, I think ruthful is fine.

Comment: @Dante: Please read Werrf's response and my comment on it.

Comment: @PedroGabriel I am a theologically literate regarding Christianity.  From the Catholic perspective the only thing required is for God to continue to will the existence of all those things involved, that doesn't mean he has to be actively engaged.

Comment: @James: You are correct... but the OP said "God is nowhere to be found", not that He simply ceased to intervene.

Comment: @PedroGabriel You're reading into that what you want to read.  My point is accept the scenario he is presenting and answer the question.  Or don't accept it and don't answer, up to you.

Comment: @James: So, after my disclaimer, I accepted the scenario and answered. And the OP liked my answer. And my answer was the chosen answer until Werrf replied. And I refered the OP to Werrf's answer, because I thought that it could help him. And it did. What's the problem?

Comment: Cheruvim would be an interesting choice (that I would have developed into an answer had you not written this much-more-thorough answer already), because they stand at the boundaries.  Cheruvim guard the entrance to Gan Eden to keep people out, and they are also depicted on the cover of the Ark over which God speaks in the mishkan (so they're sort of guardians of the tablets within and divine "escorts", metaphorically).

Comment: Hey, just for interest I believe the concensus is that Satan is a Cherub rather than a Seraph. This is based on a reference in Ezekiel 28 which is addressed to the king of Minos but sounds suspiciously like someone else. . . .

Comment: Also the usage of 'Lucifer' to refer to the Devil is largely a modern invention as the word appears only once in the Bible, and then only as an allusion to the constellation Lucifer.

Answer (score 23):

Well considering they aren't aligned with good or evil here are a few ideas:

- The Remnant (Those who do not fit good or evil)
- The Forsaken (Not good enough for Heaven so left behind)
- The Penitent or Repentant (Hoping to be absolved of their sin)
- The Unmarked (Neither having the mark of God or the Mark of the Beast)

For more effect you could also translate the names (Hebrew and Greek to keep with the biblical languages) or Latin (in line with the catholic texts).

Comment: Upvote because this is the only direct answer to the only direct question. The question was about what the class of beings should be named - not about hierarchies or mechanics or the biblical accuracy of the idea

Comment: @automaton Appreciated. An unfortunate trend in World Building SE is that people are more concerned with showing how smart they are than actually answering the question.

Comment: OK. Now I have to answer. The Watchers isn't a name? The list of Watchers I posted aren't names? The hierarchies I put there and that I said that the OP could chose one with properties more in line with Purgatory... aren't those names? At least my names were what the OP asked, references to Christianity and Judaism, not something invented out of the blue and completely opinion-based.

Comment: And Rephaim are also names that the OP could use. You may not like other people's answers, but it doesn't justify this kind of comments.

Comment: Well to quote: "based on ideas about afterlife in Christianity", and "Preferably I would like something that references Christianity, Judaism is OK too". Referencing and basing on != has to be theologically and biblically accurate. The names I used are not made up or opinion based, but simply takes on existing biblical references. I use english names to make them obvious to understand, but did say to look at using the biblical languages.

Comment: I'm not debating the legitimacy of our answer - it's well though out and I agree with the names you gave 100% -, just saying that the OP asked for names for a made up world BASED on but not consisting OF Judeo-Christian theology, so imposing that theology on the OP is unnecessary.

Comment: I do think your answer has some merit. Sorry if I attacked you. I simply think that what you said was uncalled for. I wasn't trying to sound smart, I was trying to help the OP. I even referred him to another answer! But I won't proceed with this line of comments anymore. You may think what you want about my answer and my reasons.

Comment: No worries man. I also did not mean to offend in any way. My comment was referring other Worldbuilding threads I've been on. I had not even read your answer when I wrote it. Sorry for the mix up

Comment: I see you posted a new comment while I was writing. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @Lu22 Just to tell you that I loved your names especially Remnant  & Forsaken. I've also upvoted your answer. I've choosen Watchers because its more "biblical" and still sounds good, and Rephaim (shade) because it sounds very cool and sinister. Again thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Dante. Thanks. The cool thing about Watchers and Shades is that both names are neutral, but can easily be shifted to good or evil if need be.

Comment: @Dante, FYI, I know a decision has already been made but 'forsaken' has too much of an evil ring to it after reading 'the wheel of time' series by Robert Jordan. I would assume that alot of your audience will have read it as it was written over 30years and only recently completed.

Comment: @everybothelps I actually drew the name "Forsaken" form when Jesus cried 'Father, why hast though forsaken me'? Just because the term is referenced as evil in another work of fiction does not apply that context to other peoples work. Elves are a prime example of this. Compare Norse, Tolkien and Long Earth elves for context.